# Hover function stays open css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code below for a couple of info boxes I have created using HTML and CSS. Is it possible to have the hover div stay open until you click the close at the bottom, and then it would slide back up and hide itself again? Would this be possible to accomplish with just pure CSS? If not, is it possible with vanilla JavaScript? Anything helps, cheers!

```css
.everything {
  text-align:center;
height:1000px;
background-color:#fcfcfc;
}

.everything:hover {
cursor: default;
}

.infobox-list {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

ul, ol, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, li, ol, form, fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}

.hr {
  border-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  margin-left:9px;
  width: 210px;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    color: #555;
    min-width: 20em;
}

.info-boxes li {
  width: 310px;
    height: 535px;
    background: #e2ecf6;
    border: 0px solid #efefef;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0 0px 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(0.75); 
}

.ptext
{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;

}

.profile
{
  margin-top:10%;
  margin-left:1px;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.performance
{
  margin-left:1px;
  margin-top:10%;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.learning
{
  margin-top:10%;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.team
{
  margin-top:10%;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.smallicons
{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

.profileclose {
margin-top:215px;
}

.infobox-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight:lighter;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 535px;
  width: 310px;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox:before { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  width: 160%; 
  height: 188%; 
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* fallback */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(46deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(46deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
} 

.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  animation-name: windowshade;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.info-boxes li .shade,
.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

section p {
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color: #6d6e71;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align:left;
}

p {
  display: block;
}

.info-boxes li .shade {
  position: absolute;
  width: 310px;
  height: 555px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #00688B;
  color: #fff;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px 10px 0;
  transform: translateY(-340px);
  animation-name: windowshade-out;
}

.info-boxes li .shade h3 {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold
}

.info-boxes li .shade p {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 3em;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.ie9 .info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  top: 245px
}

.info-boxes li:hover a {
  text-decoration: none
}

@keyframes windowshade {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-535px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}

@keyframes windowshade-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-535px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="everything">
  <br style="line-height:55px;">
  <section class="info-boxes">
    <ul class="infobox-list">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="infobox">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <img class="profile" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Profile-Icon_twnm83.png"></tr>
              <tr>
                <p class="ptext">Profile</p>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="shade">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/About-Me_dudglr.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>About Me</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Resume_tb7t02.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Resume</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497280574/Accountabilities_qfdcns.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Accountabilities
                      <p/>
                      <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="profileclose">Close</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="infobox">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <img class="performance" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Performance-Icon_bwevmx.png"></tr>
              <tr>
                <p class="ptext">Performance</p>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="shade">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Goals</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284934/EA_n8lvj1.png" </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Effectiveness Assessment</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png" </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Development Plan</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497285433/resources_b3r88g.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Resources
                      <p/>
                      <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="infobox">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <img class="learning" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Learning-Icon_p8gqbk.png"></tr>
            <tr>
              <p class="ptext">Learning</p>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png">
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>Training Plan</p>
                <hr class="hr">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-History_czttv1.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Training History</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497298863/coursefeedback_qdh1wm.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Course Feedback</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497299106/Favourites_y9gkce.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Training Favourites
                    <p/>
                    <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
   
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="infobox">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <img class="team" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/TeamIcon_as9ynw.png"></tr>
            <tr>
              <p class="ptext">Team</p>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497300652/Team_iovnl5.png">
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>Team</p>
                <hr class="hr">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Goals</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Development</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Training</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/Approval_f9y1da.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Approvals
                    <p/>
                    <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS doesn't catch clicks, so all you have to do is add a class (say `.open`) to your element on hover, and remove the class when you click the close button. However, it should always be easier to close something than to open it, otherwise it can lead to a bad, or at least strange, user experience.

Comment: It's impossible to do this only via CSS, you can add a tiny bit of JS to achieve it.